# Docker File: error Couldn't find a package.json file

Tags: node.js, docker

Hello i have a problem in my copying some files like package.json from the location to my docker with my docker file

i have this structure:

[image: od]

**DockerFile**

```
#building code
FROM node:lts-alpine

ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.7.3/wait /wait
RUN chmod +x /wait

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/api && chown -R node:node /home/node/api

WORKDIR /home/node/api

COPY ormconfig.json .env package.json yarn.* ./

USER node
RUN yarn

COPY --chown=node:node . .
EXPOSE 4000

CMD sh -c "/wait && yarn dev"
```

I am trying to make a microservice for study

my docker up --build console:

```
Building ci-api
Step 1/13 : FROM node:lts-alpine
 ---> 1c342643aa5c
Step 2/13 : ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.7.3/wait /wait

 ---> Using cache
 ---> 98545f011b21
Step 3/13 : RUN chmod +x /wait
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7bd8c942daaa
Step 4/13 : RUN mkdir -p /home/node/api && chown -R node:node /home/node/api
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bb060547299c
Step 5/13 : WORKDIR /home/node/api
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5ca192c19e1e
Step 6/13 : COPY ormconfig.json .env package.json yarn.* ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bfb9a913d9f3
Step 7/13 : USER node
 ---> Using cache
 ---> dd7ac9c6e0ac
Step 8/13 : RUN ls -l
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7278060f6c35
Step 9/13 : RUN yarn
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 37bc22262c1b
Step 10/13 : RUN ls -lart
 ---> Running in 07a15f149ccf
total 208
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           200 Jun  2 01:19 .env
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          1205 Jun  3 02:06 package.json
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           479 Jun  3 19:40 ormconfig.json
drwxr-sr-x    1 node     node          4096 Jun  3 20:42 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 node     node        170071 Jun  3 20:42 yarn.lock
drwxr-sr-x  429 node     node         20480 Jun  3 20:42 node_modules
drwxr-sr-x    1 node     node          4096 Jun  3 20:42 .
Removing intermediate container 07a15f149ccf
 ---> f687246805e8
Step 11/13 : COPY --chown=node:node . .
 ---> 3c1df6b4eb14
Step 12/13 : EXPOSE 4000
Removing intermediate container e7251996c85d
 ---> 615f635b2bf9
Step 13/13 : CMD sh -c "/wait && yarn dev"
 ---> Running in 53d0e2979796
Removing intermediate container 53d0e2979796
 ---> 0503223ebc4c

Successfully built 0503223ebc4c
Successfully tagged training_ci-api:latest
```

and this error:

```
ci-api    | yarn run v1.22.4
ci-api    | error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/home/node/api"
ci-api    | info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

--edit
the edit was to add all the output of my comannd docker up - build with respect to my dockerfile

Comment: Can you add the whole output of `docker build`? And just add `RUN ls -lart` as well in your Dockerfile before the `CMD` stage

Comment: @nischaygoyal i edit now with console

Comment: 1 thing, which I want to highlight is about, why you are not copying the whole source code? As why it only shows pacakge.json and few other files? and what you have in `/wait`? and you can try running it like `/wait && cd /home/node/api && yarn run dev`

Comment: @nischaygoyal wait is my https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait, u can reply with this? could you comment how i could do it best for me to vote up

Comment: i think n would be necessary to pull the node_modules no?